# Remove quotes from file export in PHP

Tags: php, string, variables, formatting, quotes

I've been doing some customizations for Twilio's report export code. I'm stuck on how to remove quote's within the text that appears within the "body" string. I tried str_replace( '"','',$sms )->body, and     addslashes($sms) ->body but am doing something wrong. Can you please help me find a solution to remove all quotes from body? The full code is below:

```
<?php
/**
* Download the library from: https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php
* Copy the 'Twilio' folder into a directory containing this file.
*/

require __DIR__ . '/Twilio/autoload.php';

use Twilio\Rest\Client;

/* Your Twilio account sid and auth token */
$account_sid = "hidden";
$auth_token = "hidden";

/* Download data from Twilio API */
$client = new Client($account_sid, $auth_token);
$messages = $client->messages->stream(
  array(
  'dateSentAfter' => '2020-01-01',
  'dateSentBefore' => '2020-02-01'
  )
);

/* Browser magic */
$filename = $account_sid."_sms.csv";
header("Content-Type: application/csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$filename}");

/* Write headers */
$fields = array( 'From', 'To', 'Body', 'Status', 'Date Sent', 'SMS Message SID' );
echo '"'.implode('","', $fields).'"'."\n";

/* Write rows */
foreach ($messages as $sms) {
  $row = array(
    $sms->from,
    $sms->to,
    $sms->body,
    $sms->status,
    $sms->dateSent->format('Y-m-d H:i:s \G\M\T'),
    $sms->sid
  );

  echo '"'.implode('","', $row).'"'."\n";
}
```

Comment: `str_replace( '"','',$sms->body )`

Answer (score 1):

Don't write your own serializers, the ones that already exist have logic for escaping built in already, cover *all* cases, and cover them *properly*.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php

"But I'm not writing to a file!" yes, you are. [Everything is a file.](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.io-streams.php)

Replace your echo with:

```
fputcsv(STDOUT, $row);
```

Comment: Replace the full line or insert this to replace just the echo function? If I replace the full line, I get a gateway timeout when the code runs.